# WooCommerce: filter products by attribute and hide product if variation is out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, stock

I use the built in WooCommerce filter by attribute widget which works for what I need, but my issue is, that if I filter on a size, I get all products with that size as an attribute, also when they are out of stock...

My products are created as a variable product with variations on size and color

What I want, is to filter a size and only display products in that size that is in stock.

Answer (score 2):

It **may not be possible for variable products and their variations** *(but only for other product types)*.

It can only works for variable products when stock management is handled by the product variation itself (but not by the variations).

Note that WooCommerce product query doesn't handle post type 'product_variation', but only post type 'product'.

To exclude out of stock products using widget filters (except for variable products) you can use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_product_query_tax_query' );
function filter_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query ){
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['filter_color']) && ! empty($_GET['filter_color']) ) {
        // Exclude products "out of stock"
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }

    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: You mention that it only is possible if the stock management is handled by product variation, but not by the variations, what exactly do you mean? Currently we have enabled the option for managing stock on each variant and entered the amount in stock

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code for my stores to hide product sizes that are not in stock whilst filtering.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_product_with_outofstock_variation', 10, 2 );
if(!function_exists('hide_product_with_outofstock_variation')){
    function hide_product_with_outofstock_variation( $is_visible, $id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($id);
        if ( $product->is_type('variable')) { // if variation product is out of stock
            $available = $product->get_available_variations();
            if ( $available )foreach ( $available as $instockvar ) {
                if(isset($_GET['filter_size'])){
                    $destostock = $_GET['filter_size'];
                    if($destostock ==$instockvar['attributes']['attribute_pa_size']){
                        if($instockvar['is_in_stock']){
                            $is_visible = true;
                        }else{
                            $is_visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $is_visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter_size will be converted in array if many filter being selected.
As for product variations, best if its stored in an array as well and use array_intersect to search if one of the selected item available in stock.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_product_with_outofstock_variation', 10, 2 );
if(!function_exists('hide_product_with_outofstock_variation')){
    function hide_product_with_outofstock_variation( $is_visible, $id ) {
        if(isset($_GET['filter_size'])){
                $filter_size = explode(',',$_GET['filter_size']);
                $product = wc_get_product($id);
                if ( $product->is_type('variable')) { // if variation product is out of stock
                    $available = $product->get_available_variations();
                    $available_size = array();

                    if ( $available )foreach ( $available as $instockvar ) {
                        array_push($available_size, $instockvar['attributes']['attribute_pa_size']);
                    }
                    if (count(array_intersect($filter_size, $available_size)) === 0) {
                        $is_visible = false;
                    }else{
                        $is_visible = true;
                    }
                }
        }
        return $is_visible;
    }
}
```

This code works for me

Answer (score -1):

You can hide out of stock products by checking the option of "Out of stock visibility" on the Settings page:

Woocommerce > Settings > Product > Inventory

Comment: I've already done that, but the products still show up if the size is sold out... I want to mention that almost all products are variable products and many of them also have brand, size and color as an attribute

Comment: Okay, so you are managing the stock in the variations of all the attributes correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Stock is managed on each product variantion. Is there another way to manage it? Since we have a limited amount of each size